# Is it possible to Airdrop/Transfer Steam games to another computer?

Tags: steam, macos

My friend and I both have CS:GO bought on Steam. We are at school and basically my school blocks Steam so I can't download it.

My friend has CS:Go installed already. Is it possible for my friend to Airdrop the files to me and I manually install it?

Comment: This feels more like a question to ask on [the apple SE site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) than here. It's about a game but more about the ability to airdrop application between mac products.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to play without using Steam or just install it because you have a download limit at home?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to manually install files for Steam games rather than download the game from Steam. Copy the files to this location, replacing (username) with your username:

> /Users/(username)/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike

However, you still need to log into Steam to play. There is no way around that.

Comment: this is very helpfull and logging in is fine for a bit but I dont want to download it because I would login using personal hotspot and download would take ages. Can you specify what he has to airdrop?

Comment: rauf, He would have to send you the Counter-Strike folder which is in the path that is shown above

Comment: Might be a good idea to zip up the entire directory and Airdrop the zip, then extract it on the other side, rather than trying to airdrop all the raw files.

Answer (score -3):

No there is no way to transfer games like that sorry. It has not been accomplished yet. I am a senior in high school and I have been trying it for a while now. You can't do it.